# liferay theme 503 service temporarily unavailable

Tags: jboss, liferay, themes, http-status-code-503

We have liferay theme deployed in Liferay Jboss bundle.
After deploying the war file- theme is deployed and getting "available for use" message also.

Also able to see theme in control panel.

But theme is not getting applied to liferay page. in browser console getting message - "503 service temporarily unavailable".

There are no errors in log file also.

Comment: Can we see the theme somewhere? And which version of liferay / jboss are you running?

Comment: Did you try applying some other theme to the page and then re applying the new one,or if any external script/css used in theme is available?

Comment: can you redeploy the theme and share the logs if you are getting any? Also check the external resources are present if any

Comment: And can you give the URL which creates the `503 service temporarily unavailable`?